# Invalid Mail Driver - Laravel and Mandrill

Tags: laravel-4, mandrill

How does one setup mandrill for Laravel 4.1.29

so i can use

```
     Mail::send()
```

using mandrill as driver?

I already added guzzle as dependency and use the credentials from mandrill.

I tried to use

```
  'driver' => 'mandrill'
```

but i get Invalid Mail Driver.

What other dependencies do I need?

Comment: I'm using mandrill with Laravel 4 here, your driver is still 'smtp' only the host, port, username, and password should be change in the mail config.

Comment: my MailServiceProvider is different from this one https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php

Comment: oh nvm it was Laravel 4.2

Comment: Same problem here but with 'mailgun' as the driver.

Comment: works only in Laravel 4.2.*

Comment: Whoops, missed the 4.2 comment. Thanks!